# which key of a HashMap<Integer,Integer> would be returned if using get()

Tags: java, hashmap

I was wondering that for a `HashMap` that is declared as below:

```
 static HashMap<Integer, Integer> test= new HashMap<>();
```

when we use `test.get(i)` which integer value is the key and which one would be returned as the result?

```
     for(int k=0;k<Array.size();k++)
    {
        test.put(k,0);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<NUM;i++)
{      test.replace(temp.get(i)), occurence.getOrDefault(stringToint.get(featurename), tempp.get(withThis))+1);

          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static HashMap<Integer, Integer> test= new HashMap<>();

Integer i = 3;

test.put(3, 6); //key -> 3, value -> 6

Integer result = test.get(i);
```

Then, `result` will be 6. 3 is the key and 6 is the value associated to this key. Note that first, you have to set any key/value pair, or you will get `null`.

Comment: in your example, where did you set the key?\

Comment: checkout put() method, it takes two parameters first one is the key and the second is the value, hence put(3,6) means key=3 and value=6

Answer (score 1):

```
Class HashMap<K,V>


Type Parameters:
K - the type of keys maintained by this map
V - the type of mapped values
```

The above explanation is self explanatory , now if you have both Integer types you just keep in mind the parameters types,it will remain same what ever the types you are taking

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
static HashMap<Integer/*Key*/, Integer/*Value*/> test= new HashMap<>();
```

get( key ) returns you the value associated with the input key. If your input is a primitive type, int in this case, it gets auto boxed to Integer class and you would get the value for the corresponding Integer key...which is also an Integer in your case.

Comment: you mean that is by default that the first integer is a key?

Comment: Yes. This is a datastructure that defines key to value mappings. And the first part is Key and the second part is Value.